# is it possible to add a namespace to normal class library via composer's autoloader?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I know this is highly unlikely but thought I would ask anyway.

I am using DomPdf to render pdfs.

Currently it does not implement namespaces and loads a lot of classes.

I can autoload the library with composer and "classmap": ["include/"].

Is it in any way possible to autoload this library implementing a custom namespace in order to avoid possible class name conflicts?

Or is there a tool to search and replace in a library to add namespaces?

I would prefer not to touch the library and was just wondering if there is some way this could be done with composer's autoloader.

(I don't currently have conflicts but would like to keep my libs from running into future issues by implementing namespaces wherever I can.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conflicts would arise because of two classes having the same name, the same (or absent) namespace, but reside in different files (and paths) and contain different code.

Composer autoloading cannot do anything about this.

If you come into this situation, you have to resolve it on the code level first, i.e. you have to rename one of the classes, probably moving it into a namespace and keeping it's name as a quick help. Effectively renaming it means to fix every other line of code that has references to the old class.

Fortunately this will only happen if you try to include new code into your project, so you'd be able to stop using whatever you started importing, and look around for an alternative instead.

Comment: I kind of figured that this would be the case. Had to ask to make sure. Will use a bridge class to access the library and update the namespaces and methods when a newer version is released. It should theoretically be possible to create a script to update a library with a one click operation. If I get time I will compile one.